# JBoss 7 MySQL datasource issue

Tags: java, mysql, jboss

I'm trying to create a datasource in JBOSS 7.

My standalone.xml excerpts:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
         <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampledb</connection-url>
          <driver>mysql</driver>
          <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
          <pool>
            <prefill>true</prefill>
            <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
            <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
          </pool>
          <security>
            <user-name>root</user-name>
            <password>matrix</password>
          </security>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
         <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

and I have created module/com/mysql/main directory and have put mysql jar there along with module.xml which is as below:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar"/>
            <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="javax.api"/>
      <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

and my persistence.xml uses this datasource

```
 <jta-data-source>java:/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
```

But the server start throws the error message as below.

```
New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql (missing)
```

Could you please help ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think, this problem is not specific to MySQL. I got the same error in an attempt to deploy an app using Oracle and IBM DB2 and from within JBoss Tools / JBDevStudio 5.01 ! (tried both separately - got the same result)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will help you to fix the problem.

[Jboss and mysql connector](http://community.jboss.org/message/621516)

Answer (score 2):

See https://zorq.net/b/2011/07/12/adding-a-mysql-datasource-to-jboss-as-7/

Answer (score 1):

Is the version of driver. Change for a new version. Believe, is only it!!!
I changed the driver mysql-connector-java-5.0.4-bin.jar   for   mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar, then the problem is solved.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I had to do to make it work. I used the 5.0.8 jar and it worked fine, an upgrade to 5.1.x failed so i rollbacked to 5.0.8 and up we go.

Answer (score 0):

For me, after checking over and over that all of the module.xml and standalone.xml parameters where right. I realised i was using mysql-connector-java-xxx-bin.jar ...Changed it to a non bin jar and it MAGICALLY worked :D