# Adding a mysql datasource to jboss AS 7

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jboss, jboss7.x

I am trying to add a MySQL data source to JBoss AS 7.1.1.

Below is the module.xml file I added in com/mysql/main :

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
 <properties> 
<resources> 
<resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.34_1.jar"/> 
</resources> 
<dependencies> 
<module name="javax.api"/> 
<module name="javax.transaction.api"/> 
<module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/> 
</dependencies> 
</module>
```

And this is the datasource I added in standalone.xml and standalone-full.xml:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool- name="ExampleDS" 
enabled="${mysql.enabled}" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb</connection-url>
                <driver>com.mysql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>root</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

I've also modified the persistence.xml in my app :

```
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
```

When I start the server, I get this error:

JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."MyApp.war#myAppservice"]

11:03:56,257 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"MyApp.war#myAppservice\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDSMissing[jboss.persistenceunit.\"MyApp.war#myAppservice\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDS]"]}}}

I tried the solution that was here  [JBoss 7 MySQL datasource issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139115/jboss-7-mysql-datasource-issue)

and here
https://zorq.net/b/2011/07/12/adding-a-mysql-datasource-to-jboss-as-7/

but nothing works.

Comment: There are no other errors in the log? There are 2 things which i see. First is the `<properties>` in `module.xml`. Second is you have a space in `pool- name="ExampleDS"`. Did you copy paste it? Maybe there is also some kind of encoding problem. Start with a clean JBoss and try to write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment ot delete `default-bindings context-service` in configuration file.